# Is it safe to use caulk to fill the gap between the wall and outlet cover?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Some of the outlets in my apartment were replaced recently and the outlet cover don’t sit tight to the wall since the wall is not flat. The repair guy said he can’t really push them in anymore. So he told me to use silicone to fill the gap between the cover and the wall. The gap was like 2–3mm. I used the Kwik siliconized caulk to fill it. I applied small amount of it to seal first, and waited for it to dry. Then I applied a bit more to make it look nice.

I was so careful not to put too much to drop it inside the cover or inside the wall since I’m too afraid of short circuit or fire. The caulk is thick and sticky so I don’t think I dropped it inside the outlet whole behind the cover. I’m just worried if this is safe.

[image]

Comment: A _far_ better option would be to use a foam seal designed to stop drafts. Silicone is a semi-permanent adhesive. You'll find that when you need to remove the cover, you're going to have to cut the caulk, likely pulling paint off the wall causing a bigger problem.

Comment: I'm surprised that the outlets couldn't be pushed in any more, since there's usually a fair amount of adjustment possible with them, assuming the wall box is at the right depth in the wall and it's sufficiently big enough for what's in there.  Do you happen to have any pictures of the outlet with the cover off, so we can see what it looks like and possibly offer suggestions on how to have it sit flush to the wall so your covers sit nicely?

Comment: Silicone was not the best choice, it isn't paintable. You could have used a lightweight spackle, larger cover plates or even try tightening the outlet and reinstalling the cover plate.

Comment: I know you got your answer, but is this a rental? If so, I wouldn’t do any more of this, lest your landlord notices and dings you on exit.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Comment: @matt. tighening screws on hard plastic or using a larger cover plate isn't going to make it conform better to a rough surface.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight, the suggestion was to tighten the _outlet_, which would generally bring it further into the box. Then the plate would pull tighter to the wall.

Answer (score 19):

It's not a safety concern. You won't short out electrics with most caulk, and it would take a *lot* of squeeze-out to even get to the electrical contacts.

That said, I'm confused about what you're doing here. Caulk is a bit of a hack when it comes to finishing anything--it always looks lazy and eventually collects dirt. It also ruins the clean straight lines of the cover plate.

Your question might have been about how to fit the devices and the plates to the wall better rather than about your less-than-ideal solution. See also the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). The wall in this photo does not look lumpy enough that it couldn't have been made to look acceptable.